# Python | Replacing Camera Output

Tags: python, module, camera, editing

I am currently working on a project which would take in my camera input, configure it, and then output the configured video. So whenever I used my camera, it would be showing my configured python camera output.
Are there any modules or methods for me to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Best way of doing it is by using **opencv** library. And for running your code in the backgoround you can use this: **pythonw <nameOfFile.py>**. Here is a link on how to do it:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/running-python-program-in-the-background/